# Ruby on Rails -- compatibility with browsers issues?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Both Firefox and Chrome allow me to connect to localhost:3000 when I run `rails server` but for some reason IE says "this page cannot be displayed."  Why is this?  Does it have to do with my using HTML5?  And does this mean that my RoR applications won't work for users who are using IE?

Forgive my ignorance -- I feel like this is probably a newbie question :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails is server-side and doesn't directly interact with the browser.  RoR applications certainly can work on IE.

But your application is apparently producing html and/or javascript that IE can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

Try...

1. putting "http://localhost:3000/"
2. checking your host file and make sure localhost is set back to you. 127.0.0.1